# Turn on CSS 'will-change' in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I found that in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) docs:

> [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) From Firefox 31 to 35, will-change was available, but only if the
>   user flipped the layout.css.will-change.enabled flag to true.

My question is how should I do that? In JS like below?

```
  layout.css['will-change'] = true;
```

Could anybody give me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's done through [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), which is essentially a browser pref pane for advanced users. As stated, this action can only be performed by the user viewing your site through their copy of Firefox, and cannot be enabled through your site by you.

Features such as `will-change` are still in the definition stages with experimental implementations, and therefore not ready for production use (although note that `will-change` will be made available starting from Firefox 36, which is [as yet unreleased](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/36)). In the meantime, they are implemented as browser user flags so developers can test them within the browser.